# Закрыть меню при клике на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Возникает конфликт, при клике на саму кнопку меню - меню открывается, но т.к я кликнул в области страницы, то оно сразу же закрывается

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menu').show();
});

 $(document).click( function(event){
      if( $(event.target).closest(".menu").length ) 
        return;
      $(".menu").fadeOut("slow");
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="menu-toggle">
  open menu
</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.menu').fadeToggle(200);
});

$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  //при клике вне кнопки меню, самого меню и его потомков
  if (!$('.menu-toggle,.menu').is(e.target) && $('.menu').has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.menu-toggle').removeClass('active');
    $('.menu').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="menu-toggle">
  open menu
</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240922/sidebar-closes-onclick-only-when-click-outside-of-it

Comment: Похоже, да. Очень даже может быть, что год назад сам оттуда брал.

Comment: попробовал на реальном сайте
https://sladosti38.ru/
нужно чтобы при нажатии на бургер меню открылось а потом при нажатии вне него скрывалось
http://prntscr.com/k0qkzy
по вашим примерам не получилось
может быть что-то не учел, проверьте пожалуйста сам код элементов. Возможно нужно будет дополнить вопрос

Comment: В сниппете мой пример с вашей разметкой воспроизводится корректно. Пересматривать js-код на вашем сайте, извините, не буду.